# Android emulator BUILD FAILED

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, android-emulator-plugin

Hi i am getting these two issues at the Time of Build..

1) Emulator did not appear to start; giving up

2) Build failed (Look at below error)

```
   [dx] : can't find dx.jar
       [dx] /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/dx: line 31: dirname: command not found
       [dx] /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/dx: line 34: basename: command not found
       [dx] /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/dx: line 48: dirname: command not found
       [dx] /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/dx: line 52: basename: command not found

BUILD FAILED
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:892: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:894: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:906: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:284: null returned: 1

Total time: 5 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

can i know what was the problem? or what i am doing wrong??

Comment: i already tried but not working.

Comment: @umesh I am facing same problem, please guide me If you got the solution

Comment: have you found the solution?